# putting username in url

Tags: python, html, django

so I been working on this for a couple of days now and I still dont seem to understand the problem. I am trying to get the username in the url so that you can just look up any user if you type http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/username and that users profile shows up. I have looked at other questions but I keep getting this error when I try. If anyone could help me I would be greatly appreciated.

> NoReverseMatch at /accounts/profile/admin
>   Reverse for 'viewprofile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/profile/(?P[\w.@+-]+)']

views.py

```
def view_profile(request, username):
    username = User.objects.get(username=username)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author = request.user).order_by('-pub_date')
    args = {
    'user': request.user,
    'posts': posts,

    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

in my nav bar: this could be wrong but im sure its right

```
<li><a href="{% url 'accounts:viewprofile' username%}">Profile</a></li>
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)', views.view_profile, name="viewprofile"),
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/admin, That url there. I made an account named admin so Im just trying to view the profile for it by having accounts/profile/admin or even with a different account I want to view it by just doing accounts/profile/admin2

Comment: Your error indicates that the `username` in that template tag has a null value, maybe you can show us the view that renders the nav bar so we can give an accurate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give `user` key in your context, you use `username` in your template. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: So please update your question, because as you ask it, the problem is what I pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

The URL which you're trying to match to if failing, please try this:

```
url(r'profile/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', views.view_profile, name="viewprofile"),
```